# Table with text vertically aligned (no Tikz)

Tags: tables, alignment, vertical, nicematrix

I am trying to write the following table:

```
Tarraconensis   |                               |
Baetica         |                               |Roman Spain
Lusitania       |                               |
```

```
%Here it goes today Iberian Peninsula
Coastal         | Mainland  |1. from Castilla   | This
cities          |           |2. from Catalonia  | is (kind of)
of              |           |3. From Portugal   |Iberian
all             | cities:   |...                |Peninsula
the Peninsula   |           |                   |today
```

There is no nee of vertical lines; I have just add them to state my case.
I need the middle aligned cells. I have tried some solutions proposed here, but without success.

I have tried with this code a slightly different table (here the to top level cell/label is atop of the columns), but the division into provinces and cities (oppida) is not really at the same level. And besides that the table runs out of the page:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{Hispania Romana}                                      & \multicolumn{4}{l}{Hispania recentior}       \\
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{divisa in}                                      & \multicolumn{4}{l}{divisa in}       \\
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{prouincias}                                      &      \multicolumn{4}{c}{oppida} \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{} &     maritima & \multicolumn{3}{c}{mediterranea} \\ \cline{4-7} 
    Tarraconensis cap. 1    &          Baetica cap. 2         &          Lusitania uetus cap. 3         &  Totius Hispaniae cap. 4   &   Tarraconensis cap. 5    &   Baeticae cap. 6    &   Lusitaniae recentioris cap. 7  
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Its kind of this what I need. But the coasta cities and the

Usually I fight with Latex to get through with tables (Latex allways wins...)

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: To be honest, I have a quite hard time to understand how you want your table to look like, exactly. Especially since the texts in the mockup version of your table and the texts in the actual code differ quite significantly. Could you please try to clarify that?

Comment: My apologies for the difference between the mockup version and the code. Consider the code as the output I want.

Comment: As to the MWE again accept my apologies. I edited the post again and didn't realize I had cut the preamble:  \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

Comment: Thanks for the update regarding documentclass and packages. I just added this information directly into your question so it does not get lost in the comments. I unfortunately still don't really understand how you want your table to look like. What does "Its kind of this what I need. But the coasta cities and the" mean? I guess part of your explanatory text was cropped as well?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me another error. In the mockup version there should be a simmetrical placement of "coastal cities" vs "mainland cities" (I am translating into English  but the table is to illustrate a Latin text I have translated to Portuguese). Please ignore the mockup version and consider the code version as the intended result.

Comment: What about " Tarraconensis cap. 1", "Baetica cap. 2" and "Lusitania uetus cap. 3". Do you want all of them in one line or in different rows? If you want all three of them in the same row, together with the other 4 entries, it will be very hard, if not impossible, to fit your table into the textwidth. Probably, it youlw be easier if you edited your mockup table to contain the same contents as the code varsion, but in the expected layout.

Comment: Do you mean add another row with "cap. 1" "cap. 2" "cap. 3"? Perhaps a solution. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tentative answer to see if I correctly interpreted the table you aspire to get. I used the `nicematrix` package, which is the only one needed for this table (at the moment).

The package offer the `\Block` command that:

(1) replaces both `multirow` and `multicolumn`;

(2) allow the use of `\\` (new lines) inside the cell;

(3) the content is centered horizontally and vertically;

`\Block{2-3}{..}` will generate a cell 2 rows high x 3 columns wide.

`\Block{}{..}` will generate a cell 1 row high x 1 column wide, which seems superfluous but allows dividing the bottom row into two lines (like the first) without adding a new row.

So in general the code is much simpler, easy to understand and change. The table is constructed with just three rows.

As you can see, I used landscape orientation because it wouldn't fit on a4 paper otherwise. Assuming this is "the table", other actions will be needed.

Two compilations are required the first time or if the table layout is changed.

[image: a3]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit = 4pt,cell-space-bottom-limit = 4pt} %expand the cells vertically and horizontally

\begin{NiceTabular}{*{9}{c}} % nine identical columns
    \hline
    \Block{2-3}{Hispania Romana \\ divisa in prouincias} & & & & \Block{1-5}{Hispania recentior \\ divisa in oppida}\\
    \cline{5-9} 
                                                         & & & & maritima & &\Block{1-3}{mediterranea}               \\
    \cline{1-3} \cline{5-5}  \cline{7-9} 
    \Block{}{Tarraconensis   \\ cap. 1}& 
    \Block{}{Baetica         \\ cap. 2}&
    \Block{}{Lusitania uetus \\ cap. 3}& &
    \Block{}{Hispaniae       \\ cap. 4}& &
    \Block{}{Tarraconensis   \\ cap. 5}& 
    \Block{}{Baeticae        \\ cap. 6}& 
    \Block{}{Lusitaniae recentioris \\ cap. 7}                                      \\  
    \hline  
\end{NiceTabular}
    
\end{document}
```

The option for portrait  is to divide the table in two.

[image: b3]

Comment: Thanks. Quite neat.